# Troubleshooting ODAC references in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, oracle12c, oracle-manageddataaccess

I recently upgraded my Oracle Data Access Components to 12.2.010 in a project I'm working on. I downloaded the installer from Oracle's website. Since then, the first query that I run in the program (regardless of which one that is) takes a few seconds longer than it used to. After the initial one, it seems to speed up. I also see that the following exception gets thrown (shown in the VS output window) about 6 times during each query:

```
Exception thrown: 'OracleInternal.NotificationServices.ONSException' in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

The query does eventually come back with the data that I need, but there is obviously something weird going on. It seems like it may be trying several times before it gets a connection. Any suggestions as to how I can troubleshoot this?